# Sometimes clicking and sometimes doesnt (XPATH related) - Java & SELENIUM

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I cannot provide the website to test it because it's hidden.

I have this checkbox:

[image]

MESSAGE THROWN BY Eclipse:

[image]

HTML ELEMENT:

```
<input name="check-receipt" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-json" value="74537">
```

It's XPATH (thrown by DEV Tools) is:

```
//*[@id="Datatable_ReceiptListModel"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/label/input[1]
```

I did this in order to click it:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"Datatable_ReceiptListModel\"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/label/input[1]")).click();
```

Sometimes if i use

> Thread.sleep(500);

it works but it has a strange behaviour

Comment: I understand you can't share a link to that page, but without minimal debugging we can't help here

Comment: @Prophet hey pal, do you think the XPATH is okay? i guess that's the problem

Comment: In case it does work sometimes and fails only sometimes the problem seems to be **NOT** with locator. Otherwise it would never work.

Comment: @Prophet is there any other way to write the XPATH in this case?

Comment: I'd say - definitely yes. Your XPath looks too long, but I have no idea what can we use here to make it better since.... we can't see that page

Answer (score 1):

Selenium has an object called `WebDriverWait`. You can use it to wait for certain conditions, one of them is waiting for an element to be clickable:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.
elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("XpathExpressionHere")));
element.click();
```

Also, it is a good idea to find elements using short and easy to read expressions. So, try finding your element using this expression:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.Xpath
("//input[@type='checkbox'][@value='74537']"))
```